# Veronese embeddings of elliptic curves in weighted projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and $D_k=kp$ a divisor on $E$, where $p\in E$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Then we can reconstruct $E$ from the graded ring $R(D_k)=\bigoplus_{n\geqslant0}\mathcal{L}({nD_k})$: $$E\cong \mathrm{Proj}\bigoplus_{n\geqslant0}\mathcal{L}(nkp).$$

Below is a table of what this results in for the first few values of $k$.
[image: table of veronese embeddings]

(A really useful resource here is [this problem sheet](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/Homework/graded_homework.pdf) by Miles Reid.)

I have two questions for which I can't seem to find any reference:

1. What happens if we carry on -- can we get an embedding for every value of $k\in\mathbb{N}$? If so, are they all different enough to be interesting, or is there a reason that most sources seem to stop after $5$?
2. Why do some embeddings never occur in the above sequence ***(if this is even true)***? For example, $C_7\subset\mathbb{P}(1,2,3)$.

**Edit:**
The answer to 1. is apparently that we can keep on going, obtaining embeddings in $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ (since $D_k$ is very ample for $k\geqslant3$), but they do get increasingly complicated.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Yes, I've taken that bit out now. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 3):

1. You are just considering the map defined by a linear system $|D_k|$ of degree $k$ (that $D_k=kp$ is irrelevant, any degree $k$ divisor on $E$ is linearly equivalent to $kp$ for some $p$). Any introductory book on curves will tell you that this is an embedding in $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ for $k\geq 3$.
2. This gives only one embedding type for each $k$, so other types do not appear in this way.

Comment: (Do you mean an embedding in $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ for $k\geqslant3$? Also, I've been trying to find a good reference for such things, when you say any introductory book on curves, could you maybe give an example?)

For the second part, why does $C_7=\mathbb{V}(x^7+y^2z+xz^2)$ not work? It's quasismooth, and some quick jottings seem to say that it's singular.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$, sorry -- I edited. As for a book, Hartshorne should be more than enough. For your $C_7$, we agree that it is singular, hence it cannot be the image of $E$ by an embedding.

Comment: Knew that Hartshorne would cover, just didn't see it on a quick glance through -- will have a better look. My comment was actually meant to say that $C_7$ is _non_-singular... I can't seem to find any singular points? Though I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You are right, sorry again -- I re-edit.

Comment: But we can show ([see this question, for example](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215171/ramification-divisor-on-curves-in-weighted-projective-space)) that $C_7$ has genus $1$, and we already know that it is a smooth projective curve... and thus elliptic?

Comment: Right again! The adjunction formula I used does not work in this case. This is well explained in A. R. Iano-Fletcher, *Working with weighted complete intersections*, in "Explicit Birational Geometry of 3-folds", LMS Lecture Notes 281 -- the example of $C_7$ is treated explicitely in 6.15.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I missed that when reading through. Any further ideas about question 2 as posted at all?